# How to repeat a block of code 10000 times to find V values in wilcoxon test

Tags: r

So I am finding V values of a Wilcoxon sum ranked test from 10 uniformly distributed RV's.
I can do this once like this

```
uniform=runif(10,min=0,max=1)
diff <- c(uniform - .5) 
 diff <- diff[ diff!=0 ] 
 diff.rank <- rank(abs(diff)) 
 diff.rank.sign <- diff.rank * sign(diff) 
 ranks.pos <- sum(diff.rank.sign[diff.rank.sign > 0])
```

but now I need to repeat this process 10,000 times and make a histogram out of it. How can I do this?

Comment: `hist(replicate(10000, {your code}))`

Answer (score 1):

Try setting a dataframe to save the results and use a loop like this. The plot will be designed with `ggplot2`. Here the code:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
#Dataframe for storing results
N <- 10000
df <- data.frame(Var=rep(NA,N))
#Loop
for(i in 1:N)
{
  #Code
  uniform=runif(10,min=0,max=1)
  diff <- c(uniform - .5) 
  diff <- diff[ diff!=0 ] 
  diff.rank <- rank(abs(diff)) 
  diff.rank.sign <- diff.rank * sign(diff) 
  ranks.pos <- sum(diff.rank.sign[diff.rank.sign > 0])
  #Save
  df$Var[i] <- ranks.pos
}
#Plot
ggplot(df,aes(x=Var))+
  geom_histogram(fill='cyan3',color='black')
```

The output for the plot will be:

[image]

And the results for each `N` iteration will be in `df`.

Comment: Awesome looks like it worked for me too! Now I just need to find the rejection region at 5% sig lvl,, thanks!